# CASE expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables w some records below. I was expecting to return on two distinct Keys with a 'BERRY' in Group field. However, for example the KEYs = 179526189 shows BERRY and COCA instead of just BERRY.

Table A

```
AGE AGE_IND     KEYS
34  (null)      179526189
6   N           179526390

Table B
ID          STATUS      FK_KEY
16478           (null)  179526189
16478           (null)  179526390
16479           (null)  179526189
16479           (null)  179526390
```

Table C

```
FK_ID   PRO_CODE    DEL_DT
16478   Drug        6/10/2014 12:00:00 AM
16479   Drug        (null)  



SELECT KEYS,
CASE WHEN (AGE < 18 AND AGE_IND = 'Y') AND (B.STATUS != 'S' or B.STATUS is null) THEN 'APPLE'
WHEN C.PRO_CODE = 'Drug' THEN 'BERRY'
WHEN AGE >= 18 THEN 'COCA'
ELSE 'APPLE' END as Groups,
COUNT(DISTINCT KEYS) AS CT
FROM #tableA A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tableB B
ON (A.KEYS = B.FK_KEY AND (B.STATUS <>'S' or B.STATUS IS NULL))
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tableC C
ON (B.ID = C.FK_ID AND C.DEL_DT IS NULL)
GROUP BY KEYS,
CASE WHEN (AGE < 18 AND AGE_IND = 'Y') AND (B.STATUS != 'S' or B.STATUS is null) THEN 'APPLE'
WHEN C.PRO_CODE = 'Drug' THEN 'BERRY'
WHEN AGE >= 18 THEN 'COCA'
ELSE 'APPLE' END
```

running the above query, yields

```
KEYS        Groups  CT
179526189   BERRY   1
179526189   COCA    1
179526390   APPLE   1
179526390   BERRY   1
```

Would you please tell me what is wrong with my CASE expression? so that my expected result yields:

```
KEYS        Groups  CT
179526189   BERRY   1
179526390   BERRY   1
```

Comment: Probably your OR statement here:  (B.STATUS <>'S' or B.STATUS IS NULL)  It can return not an S or null, is it possible to have a record with both NOT S and NULL thus returning 2 records?

Comment: My advise is to dump all the data out and look logically at the scenarios of data and how it would have created the CASE value you don't like. Then, simply update the case statement to correct that scenario. By the way, you can avoid writing the case statement twice if you write it as a nested select. I.E. SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM current query minus the group by and count) as datum group by KEYS,Groups

Comment: You can't get Berry in this situation as there is no `pro_code = 'FMU'`. So... there's something you aren't sharing, I suspect.

Comment: [Here's a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7bcf2/2) with your sample data and SQL showing two records in the output and no "Berry". I'm afraid if you are seeing the results you show here then you either have different data or different SQL than has been shared here.

Comment: If what you mean was `pro_code = 'drug'` for that Case condition then you do get four records because of your join between TableA and TableB which creates a result set that contains a record that fulfills multiple conditions of your case. You then group by the result of those multiple and disparate results for each key which, in this case, is superfluous. You can run without the group by and get the same answer set. In fact... if I were you I would remove all the logic except your entire FROM clause and see if that matches your expectation [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7bcf2/4)

Comment: And when you look at the result set in that [last sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7bcf2/4) you will see 4 records. Two of which will make a 'Berry' and the remaining making a 'Coca' and 'Apple'. Since this new derived field is in your GROUP BY then you end up with the same four records you started with as the `key/groups` combination gives you a distinct record.

Comment: 179526189 has actually multiple records, check its actual records (on each table) to see how many records it has.  I'm guessing it has two or more records, which satisfied both Barry and COCA cases. If so, you need to get rid of the duplicates or add more conditions to the COCA case to be more specific.

Comment: @JNevill, and others, Thank you for your great comments/suggestions. Yes, it was an error in the pro_code. there was nothing else that wasn't shared. Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by `GROUPS` so you get each one.  Choose one!  It is not clear how you are choosing `'BERRY'`, but if you want one row per `KEYS`, then the idea is to only include that in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT KEYS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN (AGE < 18 AND AGE_IND = 'Y') AND (B.STATUS != 'S' or B.STATUS is null) THEN 'APPLE'
                WHEN C.PRO_CODE = 'FMU' THEN 'BERRY'
                WHEN AGE >= 18 THEN 'COCA'
                ELSE 'APPLE'
           END) as Groups,
          COUNT(DISTINCT KEYS) AS CT
FROM #tableA A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     #tableB B
     ON A.KEYS = B.FK_KEY AND (B.STATUS <>'S' or B.STATUS IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     #tableC C
     ON B.ID = C.FK_ID AND C.DEL_DT IS NULL
GROUP BY KEYS;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help!